# What is the best way to invalidate cache in Redis?

Tags: caching, redis

I can only think of Redis messaging. But isn't that costly? I do not want to use template.expire() either because it is static. What I need is to re-populate cache whenever there is a new information in the DB. Thanks!

Comment: Cache invalidation is one of the two hard things in programming :) The rest is piece of cake.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but have you considered writing to the cache with every change of the DB?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I managed to invalidate my cache by tweaking the code (i.e. change push/remove cache element when inserting/updating/deleting). Btw, when I say messaging, I meant pub/sub. Didn't use expire either. Regards

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is tricky!